# Assign a FOR variable to an Argument/Parameter

Tags: windows, batch, script, code

Is it not possible to use a FOR variable, like %%a, and assign it to an argument/parameter, like so:

```
for /L %%a in (0,1,5) do (
  echo Argument#(%%a) is %~%%a
)
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean, but that for would never end since the increment is 0....

Comment: Did you mean for /L %%a in (0,1,5) do ....?

Comment: ` %~%%a` is invalid. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: You cannot assign values to parameters. They can only be passed on the command line.

Comment: Typo, I meant (0,1,5). Just trying to test what items a variable can be assigned to. So it looks like they cannot be assigned to parameters. I assume it's just hard coded that way as I see no logic for why it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "_cnt=0"

for %%Z in (%*);= do set "_arg=%%~Z" && set /a "_cnt+=1" & =;(
     <con: call set "_arg[!_cnt!]=!_arg!" && for /l %%L in =;(
     !_cnt! 1 !_cnt!);= do echo/ Argument #%%L is: !_arg[%%L]!
    );=

endlocal
```

---

- A simpler version is without defining a variable for each argument, just using one argument at a time in order:

```bat
@echo off

set "_cnt=0"
for %%Z in (%*)do call set /a "_cnt+=1" && call %:^) %%_cnt%% "%%~Z"

goto :eOf

%:^)
echo/ Argument #%~1 is: %~2 & exit /b
```

---

**Obs:** Produces the same output/result as the code above.

---

- Or some like:

```bat
@echo off

for /l %%L in (1,1,9)do echo "%*" | find "%%%L" >nul && =;(
    call echo/ Argument #%%~L (^%%%%~%%~L^) is: %%~%%~L );=
```

---

- Output:

[image]

Comment: thats some fancy shootin' tex.